# O que é Entity Manager?

Tags: java, java-ee

O que é o Entity Manager do Java?

Assistindo a uma aula sobre java o professor mencionou que o método `find()` de *entity manager* e que este método, quando busca um registo no banco de dados guarda o objeto numa área onde passa a ser "monitorado" e que serve como cache primário.

A minha dúvida é o que seria este entity manager? Para que ele é utilizado? E que área é esta?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html

Comment: Ah, só para deixar claro, não fui eu quem negativou você.

Comment: Pra mim é uma duvida válida, não entendi o downvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No JPA, o [**`EntityManager`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) é a classe responsável por gerenciar o ciclo de vida das entidades.

Essa classe é capaz de:

- Localizar entidades por meio do método `find` (que as localiza por meio de suas chaves primárias). Por exemplo, se `Funcionario` for uma classe de entidade (anotada com [**`@Entity`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html)) e quisermos obter o `Funcionario` de id = 123:

  ```
  EntityManager em = ...;
  Funcionario f1 = em.find(Funcionario.class, 123);
  ```
- Executar consultas usando [**JPQL**](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html) ou mesmo SQL nativo. Por exemplo:

  ```
  String jpql = "SELECT f FROM Funcionario f WHERE f.empresa = :emp";
  EntityManager em = ...;
  Empresa emp = ...;
  List<Funcionario> funcionariosDaEmpresa = em
          .createQuery(jpql, Funcionario.class)
          .setParameter("emp", emp);
          .getResultList();
  ```
- Persistir entidades. Por exemplo:

  ```
  EntityManager em = ...;
  Funcionario f = new Funcionario();
  f.setNome("João Silva");
  em.persist(f);
  ```
- Atualizar entidades no banco de dados. Por exemplo:

  ```
  EntityManager em = ...;
  Funcionario f = em.find(Funcionario.class, 123);
  f.setCorFavorita("Amarelo");
  em.merge(f);
  ```
- Atualizar entidades a partir do banco de dados. Por exemplo:

  ```
  EntityManager em = ...;
  Funcionario f = em.find(Funcionario.class, 123);

  // ...
  // ... Algum outro processo altera o estado do funcionário 123 aqui.
  // ...

  // Atualiza o estado da instância na memória de acordo com o que há no banco de dados.
  em.refresh(f);
  ```
- Remover entidades do banco de dados. Por exemplo:

  ```
  EntityManager em = ...;
  Funcionario f = em.find(Funcionario.class, 123);
  em.remove(f);
  ```

Uma instância de um `EntityManager` pode ser obtida de duas formas:

1. Injeção de dependências (típico caso usado em Spring e EJBs):

   ```
   @Stateless
   public class MeuBean {
       @PersistenceContext(unit = "testePU")
       EntityManager em;

       public void meuMetodo() {
           // Usa o em aqui.
       }
   }
   ```
2. Através do [**`EntityManagerFactory`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html) e da classe [**`Persistence`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html):

   ```
   EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testePU");
   EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
   ```

O `EntityManager` mantém as entidades que ele gerencia em um estado denominado de *managed* - são essas as entidades que ele monitora. Essas entidades são aquelas que ele cria por meio do método `find`, por meio de JPQL ou que recebe no método `persist` ou `merge`. Ele realiza cache dessas entidades, de forma que ler duas vezes a mesma entidade do banco de dados não produzirá duas instâncias diferentes - a mesma instância é retornada na segunda leitura.

Entretanto, nem todas as instâncias de entidades são *managed* - a saber aquelas que acabaram de ser instanciadas e não foram repassadas ainda ao `EntityManager` (estado *new*), aquelas que foram excluídas por meio do método `remove` (estado *removed*) e aquelas que foram desvinculadas do `EntityManager` por meio dos métodos [**`clear()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear--) ou [**`detach(Object)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach-java.lang.Object-) (estado *detached*).

Veja mais sobre o JPA, inclusive o `EntityManager`, [**neste link**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partpersist.htm).